# appDelegate and ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm new to Objective-C and I would like to know if my approach makes sense.

My application is Tabs-View based. every tab invoke a request to server.

1. In my `appDelegate` I create an instance of async socket connection to my server.
2. I click on my "Get status" tab which loads a `TableViewController` in which I need to create an internal request message and send it to server.
3. my problem is that I don't have access to the socket in the `TableViewController`, so I get access to the socket via `appDelegate sharedApplication` then I send the request message to server.
4. Since I use async socket model, the delegate which receives the server's response is the `appDelegate` itself and now I need somehow to propagate the response back to "Get status" `TableViewController`.

My question is how to do that??

maybe my approach is not good to start with and I need to use synchronous socket model.
or maybe I need to pass the socket connection as context to every view controller I open.

What am I missing?? How can I make the response to the server accessible easily from the View I sent it from?? Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: why not you create a general class for making your web service calls and declare delegate protocol in it, and implement these delegates in your service calling class to get your response in those classes

Comment: I think this approach limits to one view that can get the responses from server. 

I need a general socket class that view Views can access it and send messages to server and for specific active view that makes a request the server response would be received to that View.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different design.  The thing that makes the request should be a class that any VC can instantiate and use to make a request, probably a subclass of NSURLRequest.

Because it's a singleton, it's tempting to make the app delegate a holder of global data and behavior, but that's not it's job.

If you've got a lot of custom work to do for a server request, subclass NSURLRequest.  Run it using NSURLConnection's sendAsynchronousRequest: method.  It lets the caller pass a block to execute with the request result when it's complete.

e.g.  MyRequest.h

```
@interface MyRequest : NSMutableURLRequest
- (id)initWithParams:(NSDictionary *)params;
- (void)runWithCompletion:(void (^)(id result, NSError *error))completion;
@end
```

e.g.  MyRequest.m

```
@implementation MyRequest

- (id)initWithParams:(NSDictionary *)params {

    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        // do custom init here, e.g.
        self.URL = @"http://www.myservice.com/myrequest.json"
        [self setValue:@"bar" forHTTPHeaderField:@"foo"];      // more realistically, using key value pairs in the params dictionary
        // and so on
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)runWithCompletion:(void (^)(id result, NSError *error))completion {

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:self
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if (data) {
                                   // do something custom with the received data here,
                                   // like convert to a string and parse as json, etc.
                                   completion(data, nil);
                               } else {
                                   completion(nil, error);
                               }
                           }];
}

@end
```

Now, any VC -- or any other class for that matter -- can create one of these and use it:

```
// in MyVC.m

MyRequest *myRequest = [[MyRequest alloc] initWithParams:[NSDictionary dictionary]];
[myRequest runWithCompletion:^(id result, NSError *error) {
    // do main thread ui stuff with the result in hand, e.g.
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Comment: but my connection to the server is single TCP socket and not HTTP.
If I understand you correctly, this design needs to create a new socket for each request! correct?

Comment: yes.  however the same idea applies for a long lived connection.  create an object does the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your delegate to post a notification in the notification center. Then your table view controller registers to that notification and it can receive the information.

Something like

**In your AppDelegate**, when receiving the socket response

```
NSDictionary * userInfo = @{@"socketResponse" : response}; // assuming that response is the object to pass around
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kDidReceiveSocketResponse"
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:userInfo
```

**In your UITableViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(socketResponseReceived:) 
                                                 name:@"kDidReceiveSocketResponse"
                                               object:nil];
    //...
}

- (void)socketResponseReceived:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
     id response = userInfo[@"socketResponse"];
     // do whatever you like
}

- (void)dealloc {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: What is the proper way to pass the socket to the TableViewController?? 

What if the TableViewController and when user clicks on a button I need to invoke a request to server and process the response back in the TableViewController??

Using the NotificationCenter for this kind of task is legit?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella where to call socket function in app delegate? i have similar issue. please help

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Talha's comment for this and would not recommend using Notification Center. It would be best to create a new class that inherits from NSObject to handle the socket events, but you can also make it work using only the app delegate if you need to. To make it easy for you...

Create a link from socket class to the view controller

Define TableViewSocketEventsDelegate somewhere that both files can see. You can create a public Constants.h or something.

```
@protocol TableViewSocketEventsDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void) someSocketEvent:(int)statusCode;
//TODO: Add callbacks that make sense here
@end
```

Give the socket class (in your case the app delegate .h file) a reference to something that will ultimately handle the action (in your case the table view controller)

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TableViewSocketEventsDelegate> socketDelegate;
```

And in the .m be sure to synthesize the socketDelegate and assign it to the appropriate view controller.

Next tell the view controller that it can handle these delegate call backs.

in .h:

```
ViewController : UITableViewController<TableViewSocketEventsDelegate>
```

in .m:

```
#pragma mark - TableViewSocketEventsDelegate

- (void) someSocketEvent:(int)statusCode
{
    NSLog(@"Some socket event happened %I", statusCode);
}
```

Now all you have to do is alter your existing methods in the app delegate that deal with sockets to call the new methods

```
if (self.socketDelegate) {
        [self.socketDelegate someSocketEvent:2];
    }
```

Does that make sens to you? I would also recommend making a base class for all of your tab view controllers if they all need to deal with this same delegate.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for you answer!

When you say: "Create a link from socket class to the view controller" it's a problem because I have many view controllers and each of them shows different view that needs to request something from server. How can I make this socket class return answer to whom ever made the request?

Comment: It seems that your problem is that you don't have a reference to your different view controllers used by your tab controller. To accomplish this you must create  a property in your app delegate to hold the reference to each view controller. Inside your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the app delegate you are able to find the root view controller and save a reference to it... UITabViewController tabVc = self.window.rootViewController. From this tab controller you can find each child vc by the index and save an instance of whichever ones you need.

Comment: Yeah, that true I don't keep references to ViewControllers.
I think I read somewhere that each ViewController is opened and when not needed is destroyed and it's not a good practice to keep references to them because the concept of ViewController is to be created when needed and destroyed when finished. 
Would you agree to this??

But your approach of keeping references to the VIewControllers will probably solve my issue!

Thanks!!

Comment: I would agree to some degree (Modals, Popovers, etc.). However, if you have a tab view controller your app will always have 1 UITabViewController and the static number of child view controllers. They would likely not be unloaded when you click between them anyways since you are always going to be in focus of the parent.